# jest: Mock function have not been called in mock promise function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, promise, jestjs

I want to test my react login component, but the mock function have not been called:

Login:

```
export default class LoginPage extends PureComponent {
    static propTypes = {

        login: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        history: PropTypes.shape({
            replace: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        }).isRequired,
    };

    onSubmit = (e) => {
        this.props.login(this.state.username, this.state.password)
            .then(() => {

                this.props.history.replace('/');
            });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                ...
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

I use `jest` + `enzyme` to test this:

```
const props = {
    login: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve('success')),
    history: {
        replace: jest.fn()
    },
};

const wrapper = mount(<LoginPage {...props}/>);

const form = wrapper.find(Form);
const inputs = form.find('input');
const username = inputs.at(0);
const password = inputs.at(1);
username.simulate('change', {target: {value: 'Changed'}});
password.simulate('change', {target: {value: 'Changed'}});

form.simulate('submit');

expect(props.login).toBeDefined();
expect(props.history.replace).toBeDefined();

// this is success
expect(props.login).toBeCalled();

// this is failure
expect(props.history.replace).toBeCalled();
```

I mock two function, and the `history.replace` should be called by `login`, the `login` mocked as Promise function.

`expect(props.login).toBeCalled()` test success.

but `expect(props.history.replace).toBeCalled()` test failure.

I log `props.history.replace.mock`, it output `{ calls: [], instances: [] }`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to inform Jest about the promise you are using otherwise it will not wait for so the test is over before the promise resolves. [Here](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/tutorial-async.html#content) are the docs for testing async stuff.
Your test needs to become an `async` function. The promise needs to be stored in a variable that can be used with `await` after the form submit was fired:

```
it('does something', async () => {
  const promise = Promise.resolve('success')

  const props = {
      login: jest.fn(() => promise),
      history: {
          replace: jest.fn()
      },
  };

  const wrapper = mount(<LoginPage {...props}/>);

  const form = wrapper.find(Form);
  const inputs = form.find('input');
  const username = inputs.at(0);
  const password = inputs.at(1);
  username.simulate('change', {target: {value: 'Changed'}});
  password.simulate('change', {target: {value: 'Changed'}});

  form.simulate('submit');
  await promise;
  expect(props.login).toBeDefined();
  expect(props.history.replace).toBeDefined();

  // this is success
  expect(props.login).toBeCalled();

  // this is failure
  expect(props.history.replace).toBeCalled();
})
```